# Find value occurrences and delete nodes in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I really need help with a problem about linked lists in C.

I need to create a function where I have to read the nodes in the list and, for each node, I have to find occurrences. If the occurrences of the value are equals or greater than a variable value, this nodes must be deleted.

Example:
1->3->8->5->6->8->3->8->9

#of occurrences >= 3

So all the nodes with value 8 must be deleted.

Modified list:
1->3->5->6->3->9

Thank you so much.

Oh sorry my bad.
Yes I tried some solutions, but still didn't find one that works.
For delete all occurrences of a value I did this:

```
void deleteOccurrences(List *head, int val){
    Lista *temp = *testa, *prev;
    while(temp != NULL && temp->val == val){
        *head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = *head;
    }
    while(temp != NULL){
        while (temp != NULL && temp->val != val){
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if(temp == NULL)
            return;
        prev->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = prev->next;
    }
}
```

and for count occurrences I did:

```
bool countOccurrences(List head, int val, int occur){
    int count = 0;
    while(head != NULL){
        if(head->val == val)
            count++;
        head = testa->next;
    }
    if(count >= occur)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Then the function I'm trying to using is something like this:

```
void manageList(List head){
    while(head != NULL){
        int val = head->val;
        if(countOccurences(head, val, 3))
            deleteOccurrences(&head, val);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

This is the main:

```
int main(){
    List head;
    head = NULL;
    head = insert(head,9);
    head = insert(head,8);
    head = insert(head,3);
    head = insert(head,8);
    head = insert(head,6);
    head = insert(head,5);
    head = insert(head,8);
    head = insert(head,3);
    head = insert(head,1); 
    manageList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

where `insert()` function is just an insert at the beginning of the list.

This is the definition of the node:

```
typedef struct El{
    int val;
    struct El *next;
}ElemList;

typedef ElemList *List;
```

When I compile and run this I get a segmentation fault error.
If I try to run just the deleteOccurrences() function or the countOccurrences() function, they work as expected.
The problem is in this function manageList() that I don't understand how to read the list and in the same time find the occurrences and delete nodes.

Comment: Did you try something? What help do you want? Showing some effort is required for asking for homework help. Please read our [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: [Edit] to show what you have tried so far and explain the specific problem(s) and/or error(s) you found.

Comment: I guess at this point you should at least have some code that will fill the list with the values shown in your example. Show this code or whatever you may already have. If you don't know how to proceed, think about how you would solve the problem with paper and pencil and write down this algorithm. Then you can think about or ask questions how to implement this.

Comment: Sorry guys, I just asked without posting the code I tried. I updated now my answer. Thank you and sorry again.

Comment: You still need to explain what happens when you try to compile and run that code. Do you get compile errors? Does it run but give wrong output? What input do you give? What output do you get? Why is that wrong? "_[I] didn't find one that works_" is not a problem description. What would 'working' be, and why does this code not achieve that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that info; essential details should not be left in comments. Also, you need to show how you call `manageList()`, with what input. Also, you probably don't really want to pass structure by value as you currently are, as that copies all their members; probably you want to pass by pointer or pointer-to-const.

Comment: @underscore_d it worked thank you!! I passed the structure by pointer and after delete all the occurrences, I set the pointer to the beginning of the list in the while loop.
Thank you so much for all hints!

Answer (score 0):

```
void manageList(List *head){
    ElemList *cur = *head;
    while(cur != NULL){
        int val = cur->val;
        if(countOccurences(cur, val, 3)){
            deleteOccurrences(cur, val);
            cur = *head;
        }else
            head = head->next;
    }
}
```